# Command line to list users in a Windows Active Directory group?

Tags: windows, active-directory

Is there a command line way to list all the users in a particular Active Directory group?

I can see who is in the group by going to *Manage Computer* --> *Local User / Groups* --> *Groups* and double clicking the group.

I just need a command line way to retrieve the data, so I can do some other automated tasks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

try

```
dsget group "CN=GroupName,DC=domain,DC=name,DC=com" -members
```

Comment: You probably need to do a little more in order to resolve members and duplicate members in nested groups.

Comment: `dsget group "CN=GroupName,DC=domain,DC=name,DC=com" -members -expand` gets you the members in the nested groups, though it may not help with duplicates, and it gives you the full AD query string for the member, not just their CN.

Comment: Command not found on Win7 SP1. I'm guessing you need RSAT installed?

Comment: 'dsget' is not recognized as an internal or external command,etc..

Comment: @adolfgarlic - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514599/windows-7-powershell-cannot-find-dsquery-and-dsget

Answer (score 301):

Here's another way from the command prompt, not sure how automatable though since you would have to parse the output:

If group is "global security group":

```
net group <your_groupname> /domain
```

If you are looking for "domain local security group":

```
net localgroup <your_groupname> /domain
```

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted... the output might require a little parsing, but it has the advantage of depending only on utilities that are part of the base windows install.

Comment: But is there any way around the truncated group names?

Comment: Note that this isn't recursive and doesn't list groups that are in a group. Not very helpful if you have nested or hierarchical groups.

Comment: This works perfectly for me (and goes nicely hand in hand with `net user /domain`). Thanks!

Comment: For some reason I am getting error "The group name could not be found." for a group that I *know* exists.

Comment: This works perfectly for  me >net user <USERNAME> /domain

Answer (score 51):

Here's a version of the ds command I found more typically useful, especially if you have a complex OU structure and don't necessarily know the full distinguished name of the group.

```
dsquery group -samid "Group_SAM_Account_Name" | dsget group -members -expand
```

or if you know the CN of the group, usually the same as the SAM ID, quoted in case there are spaces in the name:

```
dsquery group -name "Group Account Name" | dsget group -members -expand
```

As stated in the comments, by default the ds* commands (dsquery, dsget, dsadd, dsrm) are only available on a Domain Controller.  However, you can install the Admin Tools pack from the Support Tools on the Windows Server installation media or [download it](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c16ae515-c8f4-47ef-a1e4-a8dcbacff8e3&DisplayLang=en) from the Microsoft Download site.

You can also perform these queries using PowerShell.  PowerShell is already available as an installable feature for Server 2008, 2008 R2, and Windows 7, but you'll need to [download the WinRM Framework](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968930) to install it on XP or Vista.

To get access to any AD-specific cmdlets in PowerShell you will *ALSO* need to perform at least one of the following installs:

- For Win 7 and 2008 R2 clients, you can install the [Remote Server Admin Tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449475%28WS.10%29.aspx).  The RSAT also *requires* that you have installed the Active Directory Web Services feature on your **Server 2008 R2** Domain Controllers, or the [Active Directory Management Gateway Service](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=008940c6-0296-4597-be3e-1d24c1cf0dda&displaylang=en) for any **Server 2003/2008 DCs**.
- For any XP or higher client, download and install the [Quest ActiveRoles Management Shell for Active Directory](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx).  The Quest tools do not require any additional changes to your DCs.

Comment: I use the first query all the time

Comment: Be aware that you have to run this command on the domain controler.

Comment: You *DO NOT* have to run this command on a Domain Controller.  However, you *DO* need to have installed the Admin Support Pack .msi which is included in the Support Tools on the Windows 2003 Server CDROM.  Or download it from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c16ae515-c8f4-47ef-a1e4-a8dcbacff8e3&DisplayLang=en

Comment: Regarding dsquery and Admin Tools pack, it's worth noting that "Starting with Windows 10 October 2018 Update, RSAT is included as a set of "Features on Demand" in Windows 10 itself.", see https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=45520

Answer (score 30):

For a PowerShell solution that doesn't require the Quest AD add-in, try the following

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADGroupMember "Domain Admins" -recursive | Select-Object name
```

This will enumerate the nested groups as well.  If you don't wish to do so, remove the *-recursive* switch.

Comment: You're correct that the ActiveDirectory module doesn't require the Quest ActiveRoles AD snap-in, but it does require that you have the RSAT tools installed and that your AD has at least one DC with either the Active Directory Web Service (for 2008 R2) or the Active Directory Management Gateway Service (for 2003, 2008 DCs) installed.  See my answer above for details and links.

Answer (score 18):

A very easy way which works on servers and clients:

```
NET GROUP "YOURGROUPNAME" /DOMAIN | find /I /C "%USERNAME%"
```

Returns 1 if user is in group YOURGROUPNAME, else will return 0

You can then use the %ERRORLEVEL% value (0 if user in group, 1 if not) like

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 NET USE %LOGONSERVER%\YOURGROUPSHARE
```

Comment: The "net group" command searches only domain (or domain tree) where the computer is joined. A more modern alternative is: 
`whoami /groups | find /I /C "YOURGROUPNAME"`

Answer (score 9):

Using PowerShell and Quest Software's Free ActiveRoles Management Shell for Active Directory, you can use:

**(Get-QADGroup "GroupName").Members**

http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx

Comment: Also: Get-QADGroupMember 'GroupName'

Comment: It looks like the AD tooling from Quest may now be defunct and the link currently redirects to https://www.oneidentity.com/products/active-roles/ for a paid product called Active Roles

Comment: Oh well, that sucks. It was good while it lasted.

Answer (score 7):

The answers here using `dsget` and `dsquery` will only work on server versions of Windows as those command's aren't shipped on other versions of Windows (e.g. Windows 7).  On machines without those commands you can get the information you want using the [AdFind command](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/adfind/).

Here's an example query for getting group membership:

```
AdFind.exe -default -f name="Domain Admins" member -list
```

Comment: ADFind.exe is a third party tool you have to install anyway.  The ds* commands are installable via the Admin Tools pack.

Answer (score 4):

For display members of the `UserGroup1` try:

```
dsquery group -name UserGroup1 | dsget group -members | dsget user -display
```

Comment: Might want to point out what CLI utility you'd use this in.  I don't think that's gonna work too well from `cmd`, for some reason.

Comment: @HopelessN00b: this works in cmd

Comment: @Pete Newp!  `dsget failed:'Target object for this command' is missing.`

Comment: @HopelessN00b: I get error if UserGroup1 doesn't exist, try something like "Accounting*"

Comment: @Pete: HopelessN00b is right, this requires a set of tools that are not coming with every version of windows.

Comment: @petrosmm This is an old post, and perhaps "this works in cmd (if you have the right tools installed)" would have been a more complete comment. I get your point, but in this case Hopelessn00b is wrong. The command works in cmd. He has this tool installed, otherwise he wouldn't get an error from dsget. His dsget is failing because his dsquery isnt piping in a valid group.

Answer (score 4):

How to list local groups and users?

Use the following powershell script to list the local groups and members of those groups.

```
$server="YourServerName"
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$server,computer"

$computer.psbase.children | where { 

$_.psbase.schemaClassName -eq 'group' } | foreach {
    write-host $_.name
    write-host "------"
    $group =[ADSI]$_.psbase.Path
    $group.psbase.Invoke("Members") | foreach {
$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', 

$null, $_, $null)}
    write-host
}
```

Copy the text above in to notepad and save as `filename.ps1`. Then run the file. I should display the Groups and Users in each group, or you can just run this from powershell.

Comment: I get, `cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 1. Supply values for the following parameters:` and then in asks for input, `Process[0]`

Comment: @MikeS ... Something like this perhaps: `$computer.psbase.children | ? {$_.psbase.schemaClassName -eq 'group'} | ? {$_.Name -eq 'Group Name 123'} | % {$group =[ADSI]$_.psbase.Path;$group.psbase.Invoke("Members") | % {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null) | % {"$_@domain.com"}}};`