# Active Directory: How to answer "does this user belong to this group (directly or indirectly)"

Tags: windows, active-directory, user-management

There are various ways to either [list all users & groups belonging to a group](https://serverfault.com/questions/49405/command-line-to-list-users-in-a-windows-active-directory-group) (or [via gui](https://serverfault.com/questions/66801/find-members-of-active-directory-domain-group)), or conversely [list all groups a group or user belongs to](https://serverfault.com/questions/319328/output-list-of-users-groups)...

However, I am in a position where I wish to know whether a group (`My Group`) directly or indirectly contains a particular user (`jsmith`), e.g.

- Yes, `jsmith` is a member of `My Group` or one of its members (recursively); or
- No, `jsmith` is not a member of `My Group` or any of its members (recursively).

I don't need to enumerate all possible users of the group (unless that's the most efficient way to do it).

It would be a bonus if it indicated the heirarchy through which the membership arises, e.g.

- `My Group` contains `Some Other Group`, which contains `Some Team Group`, which contains `jsmith`; or
- `My Group` contains `Poorly Maintained Group`, which contains `Domain Users`, which contains `jsmith`.

What would be the best way to answer either of these questions?

Comment: Using what mechanism? vbscript? wmi? ldap? other?

Comment: Additionally, what language would you use to access the mechanism?

Comment: Whilst not the answer you are looking for, a quick one off way of testing this is to set a permission somewhere on your local file system in a temporary location using the group, then use the `effective permissions` tool to see if the permission applies to the user in question.

Comment: @JoelCoel I'm happy to use any mechanism available; I need it to do point lookups when specific issues arise, so whatever tool or language does it best is fine with me.

Comment: @Redmumba I would be using it interactively, so I'm not concerned about language. If it's only available as an API, I could write a program/script to access it, but if it's a gui or command-line tool, that's okay too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the calculated attribute in Active Directory "tokenGroups" that returns SIDs of all groups the user belong to.

Comment: +1 That looks like what I want... Will test it later today...

Comment: I haven't been able to test this (haven't been around an AD last week), but google suggests that it would do the right thing. I haven't forgotten about this, will come back to accept it soon.